# Why is the select display showing the value instead of the label?

Tags: javascript, datatables, jquery-datatables-editor

I'm trying to use a select with inline editing. I have gotten this to display properly using the popup for editing, but I want it all to be inline and submit on blur. My data includes both an ID and a name for each dropdown item, which I have in an object that looks like { label: "blah", value: "blah" } etc.

However, in the DataTable the dropdowns are all being displayed with the ID instead of the label as the default value. I don't want users to see the id. I tried setting the editor field name to be the label and the DataTable column to be the value, which seemed to work for the popup but for inline editing I get the error "Uncaught Unable to automatically determine field from source. Please specify the field name".

My initializations look like this:

```
editor = new $.fn.dataTable.Editor({
      ajax: 'url',
      table: '#table',
      idSrc: 'id',
      fields: [{
          label: "Location",
          name: "location_name", //this is where the problem is, I think
          type: "select",
          ipOpts: locationList
      }]})

 $('#table').dataTable({
      dom: "Tfrtip",
      "searching": false,
      "ajax": {
          "url": "url",
          "type": "GET"
      },
      "columnDefs": [
        { "visible": false, "targets": [8] }
      ],
      "columns": [
          { "data": "location_id" }
      ])}
```

If I change the DataTable to use the name, the display is correct, but I get the name submitted to the database instead of the ID, and I need the ID.

What should I do?

Answer (score -1):

I did it like this, it's messy but works:

Each editable object has it's own span class. An ID that relates to the parent object. A key that relates to the object that is being updated. And then of course the data.

```
<td><span class="dcmeta" data-value="'.$row['DATACENTER'].'" data-type="select" id="'.$row['CLUSTERNAME'].'" key="DATACENTER">'.$row['DATACENTER'].'</span></td>
<td><span class="tiermeta" data-value="'.$row['TIER'].'" data-type="select" id="'.$row['CLUSTERNAME'].'" key="TIER">'.$row['TIER'].'</span></td>
```

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {  
    $.fn.editable.defaults.mode = 'popup';
    $('.xedit').editable(); 
    $('.tiermeta').editable({
    title: 'Test title',
    source: [
          {value: 'Tier 1', text: 'Tier 1'},
          {value: 'Tier 2', text: 'Tier 2'},          
       ]
    }); 
    $('.dcmeta').editable({
    title: 'Test title',
    source: [
          {value: 'DC1', text: 'DC1'},
          {value: 'DC2', text: 'DC2'},           
       ]
    });     
    $(document).on('click','.editable-submit',function(){
    var key = $(this).closest('.editable-container').prev().attr('key');
    var x = $(this).closest('.editable-container').prev().attr('id');
    var y = $('.input-metadata').val();
    var z = $(this).closest('.editable-container').prev().text(y);
        $.ajax({
            url: "process.php?id="+x+"&data="+y+"&key="+key,

            type: 'GET',
            success: function(s){
                if(s == 'status'){
                $(z).html(y);}
                if(s == 'error') {
                alert('Error Processing your Request! ');}
            },
            error: function(e){
                alert('Error Processing your Request!! ');
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo );
if( $conn === false ) {
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
if($_GET['id'] and $_GET['data'] and $_GET['key'])
{
$id = $_GET['id'];
$data = $_GET['data'];
$key = $_GET['key'];
$sql = "update CLUSTER set $key='$data' where CLUSTERNAME='$id'";

echo 'success';
$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql );
    if( $stmt === false) {
        die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true) );
}
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Could you explain exactly what you are doing here? I'm a little confused since it seems that your dropdown doesn't have specific IDs (the value and the text are the same).